# How to move from UIView to UIViewcontroller on button action

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a button on an `UIView`, and want to initialize a `UIViewcontroller` on button click. I am trying to show another `ViewController` on button click but I am getting error as :

> reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key AboutUser.'

```
// Protocol in UIView Class
protocol TinderCardDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didInfoButtonTapped()
}

class TinderCard: UIView {
    @objc func info_Btn_Action(sender: UIButton) {
       print("tap")
       delegate?.didInfoButtonTapped()        
    }
}

// Code in UIViewController
class SwipeViewController: UIViewController 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func btninfoTapped() {
        print("tappp")
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: 
        "UserProfileInfo", bundle: nil)

        let vc: UserInfoViewController = 
        storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
        "UserInfoViewController") as! UserInfoViewController

        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
 }

extension SwipeViewController : TinderCardDelegate {

    func didInfoButtonTapped() {
         print("Button tapped ")
         self.btninfoTapped()
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your storyboard connetion

Comment: check your outlets and make sure all the outlets are related to that view controller only in which you have you view not any other view controller this might happen when you have copied your view another view controller to your view controller

Comment: duplicate outlet is there Please remove action add it again

Comment: what is delegate in `TinderCard`? Where are you registering gesture for `@objc func info_Btn_Action(sender: UIButton) `. `SwipeViewController` is conforming to `TinderCardDelegate` but there is no information to which element it is delegate. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to provide as much code as possible that is related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key AboutUser.'

Reply : mab be you copy paste button from another controller Please remove action of that class and give action for that class

Comment: can u please share story outlet screenshot